# Illegal Configuration: The Value outlet from the TableViewController3 to the UILabel is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7.1

I'm trying to connect my code to UI. It's not the first time I do it but a get a weird error saying:

`Illegal Configuration: The Value outlet from the TableViewController3 to the UILabel is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content.`

I've checked all the labels and they are not connected to deleted code lines.
How can I solve it?

Comment: Is the outlet connected to a label inside a cell?

Comment: Yes, it's in a cell but I've used to do this in other app and it worked well.

Comment: It shouldn't work with a dynamic table.  You're telling one outlet to point to a label object but there could be many copies of that label on the screen at the same time.  If you have a custom cell class with an outlet that points to a cell label, **that** should work because it would be one-to-one.